# Discoloured Malabar Spinach leaves

Tags: diagnosis

I have Malabar Spinach planted in three pots. In the third one, the leaves are very healthy while the other two have discoloured new leaves. What is the cause of it?

[image]

Comment: How big are the pots the discoloured ones are growing in? What soil did you use in the pots?

Comment: Pot 1 is 30 cm wide 26.5 cm long and 19 cm potting mix filled. Pot 2 is 40 cm x 22.5 cm x 11 cm. Mix is 3:3:1 cocopeat:vermicompost:perlite regularly amended with seaweed emulsion. It had corn planted previously. Before it it was new. I added mustard/neem cake tea 6 days before and now it is raining and the bigger pot's leaves have turned greener.

Comment: The third one is same except it is new and has 1 part vermiculite and a bit of neem cake added as well.

Comment: I wanted to add vermicompost to the first and second pots but waited since I had added mustard cake tea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pots seem to be big enough, but the plant needs fertilizer - the discoloration is indicative of nutrient shortage.

Comment: Thanks! One question though- Can I used mustard/neem/compost teas in rainy season? Some say it will cause fungal infection. But can I use it with a spray of neem oil?

Comment: I really don't know - where I live, I'd just use a chemical fertiliser like Miracle Gro, with a stated NPK readout - with compost teas, you don't know what the nutrient levels are because there's no NPK. I'm just trying to think of a reason why using compost tea might encourage fungal infection,and I don't know of one, though I suppose it being rainy season, fungal infections are more likely generally